# Подскажите что означает такое сравнение *p && *p != ch;

Tags: c++, visual-c++

подскажите *p && *p != ch; внутри цикла поиска символа в строке почему так сделано а не так  *p != ch; или в приведенном выше примере ошибка?

Так выглядит:

```
const T *p;
for (p = str; *p && *p != ch; p++);
return p;
```

Comment: Не нулевой символ и не `ch`; т.е то же, что и `*p != 0 && *p != ch`...

Comment: @Harry О благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*p && *p != ch, используется в условии цикла для поиска символа в строке.
она обеспечивает двойную проверку: на конец строки и на наличие искомого символа, прежде чем цикл завершит выполнение. Если условие было бы просто *p != ch, цикл завершался бы, как только был бы найден искомый символ, независимо от того, является ли этот символ концом строки или нет.

Comment: `Если условие было бы просто *p != ch, цикл завершался бы, как только был бы найден искомый символ, независимо от того, является ли этот символ концом строки или нет.` Ну с условием `*p && *p != ch` цикл также завершится, если будет найден искомый символ, независимо от того, является ли этот символ концом строки или нет.